# How to do Seq.unzip

Tags: f#

I have a `foo: seq<int*int>`

I want to split the tupled items and then store the results to two variables, each a `seq<int>`

I was wondering if there was a prettier way to do this, e.g.

```
let item1, item2 = foo |> ?????
```

My current solution:

```
let item1 = foo |> Seq.map(fun (f1,_) -> f1)
let item2 = foo |> Seq.map(fun (_,f2) -> f2)
```

Comment: point noted. What I'm actually doing is more complicated than just me doing foo |> Seq.map(fst) or Seq.map(snd). My main question is more along the lines of what I can do to avoid doing two Seq.maps

Comment: If what you're doing is "more complicated", then tell us what it is, there is no point in answering the question when it's not really the question.

Comment: What you want is Seq.unzip, like [List.unzip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340249.aspx) however for the[Seq module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx) it does not exist. This can be confirmed by looking at F# 4.0 what's new in section `Normalized collections modules` we find [Seq.unzip](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/00/00/01/39/71/metablogapi/3125.collectionAPI_254EA354.png) is not there.

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you Guy Coder. unzip is what I was looking for. I'm okay with converting this Seq to a List.

Comment: I think Seq.unzip is not part of F# because it requires the input sequence to be enumerated twice. This is potentially inefficient and could produce unexpected results if the sequence has side-effects.

Comment: @BrianBerns that's exactly right! Though there actually already are functions that do a `Seq.cache` first, so technically that could be the solution here. However, it's too subtle and specific, better to leave that to the user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly, there is no drop-in `Seq.unzip` function included in the language, although equivalents for Lists (`List.unzip`) and Arrays (`Array.unzip`) do exist.

There are a few ways of defining such a function, one method is this:

```
let unzip sequence =
    let (lstA, lstB) = 
        Seq.foldBack (fun (a,b) (accA, accB) -> 
            a::accA, b::accB) sequence ([],[])
    (Seq.ofList lstA, Seq.ofList lstB)
```

Alternatively, if you don't care about switching back and forth between list, you can just do:

```
let item1, item2 = 
    let it1, it2 = 
        foo 
        |> List.ofSeq 
        |> List.unzip 
    (Seq.ofList it1, Seq.ofList it2)
```

Comment: That proposed implementation also switches back and forth between `seq` and `list`; is it better?

Comment: @MarkSeemann Yes, it should be.  Going from `List` to `Seq` is cheap because `List` is already a type of sequence.  Going from `Seq` to `List` is going to be expensive because that involves enumerating and building a list.

Comment: @MarkSeemann For reference, it appears `Seq.ofList` is just implemented using upcast in F# core: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L1216

Comment: I wanted to compare the two alternatives, but assuming that `foo` is a `seq<int * int>`, the second alternative doesn't compile.

Comment: @MarkSeemann You're right, I thought I had tested it but the second function was wrong.  I've fixed it.

Comment: Trying out these alternatives in FSI with a sequence with 1,000,000 elements, it looks as though the second alternative is slightly faster than the first: just shy of 1 second, versus 1.3 seconds. Obviously, these casual measurements are far from conclusive, but I hope they demonstrate that one can't *reason* about performance.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Absolutely true.  I'd have expected the first to be faster because F# core generally implements intermediate Seq operations with arrays.  It's very possible there are other, more significant, factors at work here though.

Comment: Performance aside, I would argue that both of those implementations are incorrect, simply because they are eager. I would expect `Seq.unzip` to be a lazy function, exactly like `Seq.map`, and if I wanted it to be eager I'd compose it with `Seq.cache`. In other words, the OP's implementation seems like the correct one to me.

Comment: @piaste You absolutely wouldn't write a library sequence function with two enumerations of the sequence contained.  To implement this in F# core, it'd probably be done with a mutable append collection (e.g. `ResizeArray`) and `mkDelayedSeq`.  That approach would also produce a considerable performance gain compared to these simple examples.  I'm happy to provide an example if there is interest.

Comment: @TheInnerLight Thanks, if you could post a gist or something that'd be great. I looked at the definition of `mkDelayedSeq` and it looks like just a lazy wrapper over `GetEnumerator()`. That makes me think that using it on a `ResizeArray` would cause the original sequence to be fully enumerated (to build up the `ResizeArray`) whenever you accessed just the first element of either of the unzipped sequences, but I probably just misunderstood you.

Answer (score 5):

What you want to get are two different sequences, so you won't find a much prettier way to do this. What you have is almost sufficient, but you can make it a bit shorter by using `fst` and `snd` for teasing first and second items of the tuples respectively, and writing both expression on the same line:

```
let items1, items2 = foo |> Seq.map fst, foo |> Seq.map snd
```

Answer (score 5):

To add on TheInnerLight's answer, the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/sequences-%5Bfsharp%5D) tells us that :

> Seq.zip and Seq.zip3 take two or three sequences and produce a sequence of tuples. These functions are like the corresponding functions available for lists. There is no corresponding functionality to separate one sequence into two or more sequences. **If you need this functionality for a sequence, convert the sequence to a list and use List.unzip**.

My spontaneous solution (similar to the OP's approach) would have been to write :

```
let unzip sequence = 
    let source = Seq.cache sequence
    Seq.map fst source, Seq.map snd source
```

(I tested it in FSI for 1000000 elements and it is also a bit slower than the List.unzip approach on my computeur)

Comment: thank you for this additional info. For the record, the original title was modified by someone else -- Previously, I was not even aware there was a List.unzip

Answer (score 4):

For lists and arrays, these functions are built-in:

```
> [(1, "foo"); (2, "bar"); (3, "baz")] |> List.unzip;;
val it : int list * string list = ([1; 2; 3], ["foo"; "bar"; "baz"])
> [|(1, "foo"); (2, "bar"); (3, "baz")|] |> Array.unzip;;
val it : int [] * string [] = ([|1; 2; 3|], [|"foo"; "bar"; "baz"|])
```

It doesn't exist for `Seq`, though.

Comment: You answered slightly first, but I'm giving the answer to TheInnerLight for providing a Seq.unzip function. Thank you for your help! Love your blog.